# Ubuntu 20.04 - can't upload Arduino's sketch

Tags: serial-port, arduino

After a fresh install of Ubuntu, I tried to upload sketch using Arduino IDE v1.8.16 (installed using a `.deb` file downloaded from web).

`An error occurred while uploading the sketch avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Device or resource busy`

After a first install of Arduino IDE on a new Linux machine need to be a member of : `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER` and logoff, logon ,which didn't change as expected.

So I tried to `chmod` of connected port `/dev/ttyUSB0`, which didn't change the error message ( by the way, also on USB1, and ACM0 I got the same output- when trying to upload to `Nano`).

Now I get this error:

```
esptool.py v3.0
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/guy/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.2/tools/upload.py", line 66, in <module>
    esptool.main(cmdline)
  File "/home/guy/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 3552, in main
    esp.connect(args.before, args.connect_attempts)
  File "/home/guy/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 529, in connect
    raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

To verify it is not an IDE error, I tried using `esptool.py` to erase flash, and I got the same behaviour `Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____`

Comment: An error regarding Serial port is known Do you mean there is a known error or are you referring to the error you received?

Comment: @David perhaps a not optimal explanation, try this:  After a new installation of ubuntu ( or first time using Arduino IDE on a PC, there is a need to add user to the `dialout` group

Comment: Very different from what the question says. Maybe edit the question.

Comment: question edited as mentioned

Comment: Nano seems to be Arduino. While esptool is used for Espressif ESP8266 and/or ESP32. Please clarify the used hardware MCU model.

Comment: The bug now seems to be fixed (e.g. in "5.4.0-91-generic")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this happens to the latest ubuntu with the latest kernel and several versions of arduino-ide ( from snap, from apt install, even with the latest version installed from arduino's website )
tried several board version's
tried modded esptool
tried not-modded esptool
tried several (not charge only) cables
tries several esp32 boards and esp32 vendors ( wemos, nodemcu, etc. )

I believe that there might be a problem with the serial driver?
All boards are working great on windows with all versions of arduino-ide tested on Ubuntu 20.04, and same cables.
I ruled out any possible problem in regards to : software (ide), cables, boards.

will dig more into this.

LE: Found the issue!
Looks like there is a bug in the kernel driver for ch340/ch341
I had one old kernel installed ( 5.9.x ) and with this one works.
That took me to some search over the internet :) so [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214131) it is

> ```
>       Bug ID: 214131
>      Summary: ch341 communication problem
>      Product: Drivers
>      Version: 2.5
> ```
>
> Kernel Version: 5.14-rc5
> Hardware: All
> OS: Linux
> Tree: Mainline
> Status: NEW
> Severity: normal
> Priority: P1
> Component: USB

It looks to me that starting kernel 5.10.x till 5.14-rc5 the bug is present.

Happy coding guys

Comment: So from what I understand, there's no end user solution here but to wait for an update? This is troublesome but strangely enough, my Arduino Nano running on CH340 runs just fine. Only the ESP boards experience the problem.

Comment: Seems to have fixed itself after recent kernel patch for me, before that booting into 5.3.0-64 worked as a temporary fix.

Comment: I have held back the kernel which works until an update comes https://askubuntu.com/questions/938494/how-to-i-prevent-ubuntu-from-kernel-version-upgrade-and-notification

Answer (score 4):

Workaround for ESP boards:

Settings prior to uploading the sketch:

- Boardtype: Generic ESP8266
- Flash size: 4MB
- Reset method: "dtr (aka nodemcu)" (default)

Then:

1. Change reset method to: "**no dtr (aka ck)**" (Tools -> Reset Method)
2. Then press Flash button
3. Press Reset shortly
4. Then release Flash
5. Upload sketch in the Arduino IDE

[image: Arduino]

Source: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/manjaro-21-1-0-und-esp8266-sketch-upload-doesnt-work-anymore/79712/2

Note: Tested on ESP8266 (NodeMCU)

**Update:**

This issue has been fixed in the latest kernel version. Please update the kernel and test again.

Comment: I tried it already as it seemed like ESP32 or pro micro waiting for that reset ( not successfully though)

Comment: @Guy.D I successfully tested on ESP8266 (NodeMCU)

Comment: I cannot find "Tools -> Reset Method". Is it in Arduino IDE, next to Board/Upload Speed/Debug Port/...?

Comment: @EricDuminil You have to select correct board e.g. 'Generic ESP8266 Module'

Comment: @DevTomek: Thanks. I downgraded my kernel, but it's good to know that other temporary fixes are available.

Comment: how do i update kernel only ?

Answer (score 3):

with kernel linux-image-5.4.0-87-generic @ ubuntu 18.04 I have exactly the same problem (running latest arduino, board definitions and libz), when I reboot to 5.4.0-86-generic it works again, dunno why, but spent like hour today finding out what changed (bcs I use arduino for a long time on this computer and always everything worked smoothly...)

So try to boot older kernel, maybe it helps

Comment: I can confirm this works fine with "5.4.0-86-generic", on Ubuntu 18.04 and Linux Mint 19.3. This issue was really hard to track down, amid all the "RTFM, Noobie" answers telling people to press buttons, change permissions, add users to groups or use DIP switches. "5.4.0-87", "5.4.0-88" and "5.4.0-89" all have this bug. Let's hope the next version won't.

Comment: "5.4.0-91-generic" is now working fine, and I can upload again to ESP8266 with the current kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, the workaround works for me!!

5.4.0-89-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 24 14:50:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

VID: 1A86
PID: 7523

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).