# I am not familiar with terminolgy but i need help os broken

Tags: dpkg

Im running ubuntu 22.04 and i cant update anything after intalling new kernal or even log in i have to go back a kernel i try to update and i get this error "dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem" then when i do what it says it says its generating boot image and it repeats in terminal indefinitely i need help from the beggining anything what do i have to do to get some help on here please all my files are on this hd and ive never had any trouble with linux before is there anyone who can help

```
10:46:37 AM gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
10:46:36 AM systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
10:46:34 AM gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
10:46:26 AM systemd: Failed to start Service for snap application network-manager.networkmanager.
10:46:25 AM networkmanager: <error> [1690386385.7425] bus-manager: fatal failure to acquire D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (3). Service already taken
10:46:23 AM gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
10:46:23 AM networkmanager: <error> [1690386383.6760] bus-manager: fatal failure to acquire D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (3). Service already taken
10:46:20 AM logger: ERROR: Duplicate address 192.168.86.25 assigned in the network where wlp3s0 is connected to.
10:46:13 AM systemd: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
10:46:13 AM smartd: Device: /dev/nvme0, number of Error Log entries increased from 1047 to 1048
10:46:12 AM kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)
10:46:10 AM kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.THRM._SCP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
10:46:10 AM kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.THRM._SCP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
10:46:10 AM kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.THRM._SCP.CTYP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
10:46:10 AM kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
10:46:10 AM kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP4.WLAN], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
```

Im not very good at this but i posted important messages from my logs

Comment: Can you run the command `sudo dpkg-configure -a`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to I prevent Ubuntu from kernel version upgrade and notification?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938494/how-to-i-prevent-ubuntu-from-kernel-version-upgrade-and-notification)